# Unicode из python2 преобразовать в python3-код

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Помогите преобразовать 2 строчки кода `if type(s) != unicode: fixed_tweets.append(unicode(s, errors="ignore"))`(там где содержится unicode из python2 в формат для python3). Запутала окончательно в unicode

```
def get_tweets_predictions(tweets, perform_prints=True):
    fixed_tweets = []
    for i, t_orig in enumerate(tweets):
        s = t_orig
        try:
            s = s.encode("latin1")
        except:
            try:
                s = s.encode("utf-8")
            except:
                pass
        if type(s) != unicode:
            fixed_tweets.append(unicode(s, errors="ignore"))
        else:
            fixed_tweets.append(s)
    assert len(tweets) == len(fixed_tweets), "shouldn't remove any tweets"
    tweets = fixed_tweets
    print(len(tweets), " tweets to classify")
```

и в этой части кода тоже этот же unicode

```
select = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', C=0.01, max_iter=15000))
final_features = select.get_support(indices=True)  # get indices of features
final_feature_list = [unicode(feature_names[i]) for i in
                      final_features]  # Get list of names corresponding to indices
print('final_feature_list= ', final_feature_list)
```

должно получиться: `[u'america', u'american', u'anoth', u'ass', u'ass...]`

пробовала создать функцию

```
def unicode(obj):
    return u'%s' % obj
```

но не получается того, что нужно. спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: А что в реальности получается вместо должно? Так то родная кодировка 3-го питона и есть юникод `utf-8` и при выводе у него не будет никаких `u'`, это только во втором питоне такой вывод юникода.

Comment: получается без u'б но уникод везде подсвечивается, чем его заменить или как убрать

Comment: Где именно у вас юникод подсвечивается и почему это является проблемой?

Comment: везде где слово unicode в коде подчеркивается красным и пишется name not found:

Comment: if type(s) != unicode:
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: А, ну убрать эту проверку вообще и эту ветку кода ) оставить то, что в `else`

Comment: спасибо, так и сделала))

Comment: final_feature_list = [unicode(feature_names[i]) for i in
                      final_features]

Comment: а вот с этим как быть

Comment: Ну попробуйте убрать вызов `unicode`, а остальное всё оставить `final_feature_list = [feature_names[i] for i in final_features]`